# Inverse property

Tags: jena, knowledge-graph

I have noticed that most properties have an inverse property such as:

http://vocab.getty.edu/ontology#ulan1511_child_of

the inverse is:

http://vocab.getty.edu/ontology#ulan1512_parent_of

Is there a way to automatically create that property ex: Alice is the childOf John is in the knowledge Graph

How can it automatically create the property John is the parentOf Alice?

Is it possible with inferencing?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one of two properties, you can do this SPARQL Update:

```
PREFIX ont: <http://vocab.getty.edu/ontology#>

INSERT { ?o ont:ulan1512_parent_of ?s }
WHERE  { ?s ont:ulan1511_child_of ?o }
```

You can even do this in the parser input stream (needs some java to be writtern).

If it is more complex, you can use a Jena reasoner.